# scikit - random forest regressor - AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute '_children'

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn

I'm getting the following error when setting my `n_jobs` parameter `> 1` for the random forest regressor.  If I set `n_jobs=1`, everything works.

```
AttributeError: 'Thread' object has no attribute '_children'
```

I'm running this code in a flask service.  What's interesting is that it does not happen when ran outside of the flask service.  I've only repro'd this on a freshly installed Ubuntu box.  On my Mac it works just fine.

This is a thread that talked about this, but didn't seem to go anywhere past the workaround:
['Thread' object has no attribute '_children' - django + scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852680/thread-object-has-no-attribute-children-django-scikit-learn)

Any thoughts on this?

**Here is my test code:**

```
@test.route('/testfun')

    def testfun():
        from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
        import numpy as np

        train_data = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,1,3]])
        target_data = np.array([1,1])

        model = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=2)
        model.fit(train_data, target_data)
        return "yey"
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
        response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "/home/vagrant/flask.global-relevance-engine/global_relevance_engine/routes/test.py", line 47, in testfun
        model.fit(train_data, target_data)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py", line 273, in fit
        for i, t in enumerate(trees))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 574, in __call__
        self._pool = ThreadPool(n_jobs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 685, in __init__
        Pool.__init__(self, processes, initializer, initargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 136, in __init__
        self._repopulate_pool()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 199, in _repopulate_pool
        w.start()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/dummy/__init__.py", line 73, in start
        self._parent._children[self] = None
```

Comment: I don't have a solution but I'll just write the things I noticed. It seems really strange- the line just before the error specifically tests for having `_children`: `if hasattr(self._parent, '_children'): self._parent._children[self] = None`. When you say it works outside of flask, is that with the exact same environment (interpreter, libraries, os, machine, etc.)? I ask because in my system, line 73 is the condition but in yours it is the assignment. I think your flask environment is using an older version of python where [this bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue14881) is not fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The Problem

This probably happens due to a bug in `multiprocessing.dummy` (see [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue14881) and [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue10015)) that existed before python 2.7.5 and 3.3.2.

## Solution A - Upgrade Python

See the comments for confirmation that a newer version worked for OP.

## Solution B - Modify `dummy`

If you can't upgrade but have access to `.../py/Lib/multiprocessing/dummy/__init__.py`, edit the `start` method within the `DummyProcess` class as follows (should be ~line 73):

```
if hasattr(self._parent, '_children'):  # add this line
    self._parent._children[self] = None  # indent this existing line
```

## Solution C - Monkey Patch

`DummyProcess` is where this bug exists. Let's see where it exists in your imported code to make sure we patch it in the right place.

- RandomForestRegressor
- inherits: ForestRegressor
- inherits: BaseForest
- created in: sklearn.ensemble.forest
- which imports: Parallel from sklearn.externals.joblib
- which imports ThreadPool from multiprocessing.pool
- which imports and stores Process from multiprocessing.dummy
- which has been assigned to: DummyProcess also in multiprocessing.dummy

The existence of `DummyProcess` in that chain guarantees it has already been imported after the import of `RandomForestRegressor`.
Also I think we have access to the `DummyProcess` class before any instances of it are made.
Therefore we can patch the class once instead of needing to hunt down instances to patch.

```
# Let's make it available in our namespace:
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from multiprocessing import dummy as __mp_dummy

# Now we can define a replacement and patch DummyProcess:
def __DummyProcess_start_patch(self):  # pulled from an updated version of Python
    assert self._parent is __mp_dummy.current_process()  # modified to avoid further imports
    self._start_called = True
    if hasattr(self._parent, '_children'):
        self._parent._children[self] = None
    __mp_dummy.threading.Thread.start(self)  # modified to avoid further imports
__mp_dummy.DummyProcess.start = __DummyProcess_start_patch
```

Unless I've missed something, from now on all instances of DummyProcess created will be patched and therefore that error won't occur.

For anyone making more extensive use of sklearn, I think you can accomplish this in reverse and make it work for all of sklearn instead of focusing on one module.
You will want to import `DummyProcess` and patch it as above before you do any sklearn imports.
Then sklearn will be using the patched class from the beginning.

---

Original answer:

As I wrote the comment, I realized that I may have found your problem - I think your flask environment is using an older version of python.

The reason is that in the latest version of python multiprocessing, the line where you are receiving that error is protected by a condition:

```
if hasattr(self._parent, '_children'):
    self._parent._children[self] = None
```

It looks like [this bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue14881) was fixed during python 2.7 (I think fixed from 2.7.5). Perhaps your flask is an older 2.7 or 2.6?

Can you check your environment? If you can't update the interpreter, perhaps we can find a way to monkey patch multiprocessing to keep it from crashing.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I tried a fresh VM with 2.7.6 and you are right, it worked.

Comment: *adding below because i can't edit above.

My initial env was using 2.7.3.  I don't have much control of the Python version used.  However, I benchmarked out a test trial and it won't be detrimental to use a single thread.  I only need to run it once a day and it runs in < 10 minutes.  I'm assuming others might enjoy the monkey patch if it's not horridly difficult.

Comment: @HappyCamper That's good news. I'm glad it works. An upvote and solution marker would be appreciated and will help future users go the right way. As for a monkey patch, I will have to work on that as I don't see a super safe way to do it yet. I may ask another question on SO to get it but I'll do it eventually.

Comment: @HappyCamper can you please tell me your import chain to get access to `RandomForestRegressor`? E.g. `from sklearn import ensemble` followed by `... ensemble.RandomForestRegressor` . Or maybe `from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor`?

Comment: I think marked everything correctly (still getting used to posting on here).   Thank you again for looking at all of this!  

I had the import statement in the code block above.  Please let me know if this is not correct.  

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

Comment: @HappyCamper oh right! Sorry i forgot that was there. I only looked at the top of the code. When I get home I'll put something up.

Comment: @HappyCamper There is the monkey patch. I haven't tested it so if you or anyone else tried it, please post the result here.